Getting duplicate entry for Django API URL in swagger when using drf_yasg
I am getting duplicate entry in swagger when I have two API view(ListApiView, UpdateAPIView) in single class using Django rest framework
So, I have added two urls and one is for GET, POST and other url for PUT with that, I should get only 3 rows in swagger but it shows three entries for each url and I have attached the screenshot here of my url and swagger.

Following is my url pattern

This is how my class is defined
class EscalatedStatusListView(ListAPIView, UpdateAPIView):


You have two routes, one with and one without the primary key param.  Swagger generates all the verb calls for each route.

Is there any way to fix this, since I need to use separate route for DRF PUT with primary key

I have fixed after create the new url with escalated_status/update/<int:pk>/
